# Comparar dos listas en java y mostrar en una tercer lista las diferencias

Tags: java, jsf

Quisiera hacer la siguiente pregunta tengo dos listas en java la primera es el resultado de una consulta sobre una vista que me arroja la siguiente lista.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta lista me trae varios pedidos cada uno se ve de la siguiente forma los datos que mas me importan aqui son codigoBarras y pedida el usuario no ve esa lista por eso la voy a mostrar de esta manera.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La persona empieza a pitar con su pistola de codigo de barras y empiezo a llenar una tabla de la siguiente forma.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y tengo una validacion que es la siguiente.

```
public void eventoPistola() {

    System.out.println("Codigo Barras: " + codigoBarras);
    PickingPedidos pickingPedidoEncontrado = null;
    for (PickingPedidos pp : pickingPedidosList) {
        System.out.println("---> " + pp.getMProductId() + ", " + pp.getDocumentno() + ", " + pp.getCodigoBarras() + ", " + pp.getProducto() + ", " + pp.getCodigo() + ", " + pp.getExistencia());
        if (pp.getCodigoBarras().equals(codigoBarras)) {
            pickingPedidoEncontrado = pp;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (pickingPedidoEncontrado != null) {

        System.out.println("Encontrado !!!!");

        pedidoEncontrado = new PedidoEncontrado();
        pedidoEncontrado.setCodigoBarras(pickingPedidoEncontrado.getCodigoBarras());
        pedidoEncontrado.setDocumento(pickingPedidoEncontrado.getDocumentno());
        pedidoEncontrado.setPedida(pickingPedidoEncontrado.getPedida());
        pedidoEncontrado.setProductId(pickingPedidoEncontrado.getMProductId());
        pedidoEncontrado.setNombreProducto(pickingPedidoEncontrado.getProducto());
        pedidoEncontrado.setCodigo(pickingPedidoEncontrado.getCodigo());
        pedidoEncontrado.setNumeroDeCaja(numeroDeCajas);
        pedidoEncontrado.setExistencia(pickingPedidoEncontrado.getExistencia().intValue());
        pedidoEncontrado.setRemision(remision);

        if (pedidoEncontradoList.contains(pedidoEncontrado)) {
            int posicionObjeto1 = pedidoEncontradoList.indexOf(pedidoEncontrado);

            //Obtener el objeto encontrado segun la posicion                    
            pedidoEncontrado = pedidoEncontradoList.get(posicionObjeto1);
            int sumaFactor1 = pedidoEncontrado.getFactor() + factor;
            if (pedidoEncontrado.getPedida().intValue() < sumaFactor1) {
                lanzarMensajeError("Superada la cantidad pedida");
                codigoBarras = null;
            } else {

                int posicionObjeto = pedidoEncontradoList.indexOf(pedidoEncontrado);

                //Obtener el objeto encontrado segun la posicion                    
                pedidoEncontrado = pedidoEncontradoList.get(posicionObjeto);

                //Calcular la suma
                int sumaFactor = pedidoEncontrado.getFactor() + factor;
                System.out.println("YA ESTA EN LA LISTA, ACTUALIZAR SUMA A " + sumaFactor);

                //Setear la suma al objeto
                pedidoEncontrado.setFactor(sumaFactor);

                //Setear el objecto actualizado nuevamente a la lista                    
                pedidoEncontradoList.set(posicionObjeto, pedidoEncontrado);

            }

        } else {
            if (pedidoEncontrado.getPedida().intValue() < factor) {
                lanzarMensajeError("Cantidad pitada supera la pedida");
                codigoBarras = null;
            } else {
                System.out.println("AUN NO ESTA EN LA LISTA, AGREGARLO");
                pedidoEncontrado.setFactor(factor);
                pedidoEncontradoList.add(pedidoEncontrado);

            }
            codigoBarras = null;
            sumaCantidadPedido = 0;
            for (PedidoEncontrado ss : pedidoEncontradoList) {
                sumaCantidadPedido += ss.getFactor();
            }

            System.out.println("suma total: " + sumaCantidadPedido);

        }


    } else {
        codigoBarras = null;
        System.out.println("NO encontrado :(");
        lanzarMensajeEnDialogo("Este Producto no Pertence al Pedido por Favor Verifique Contra el Pedido Impreso........");

    }

}
```

Estas validaciones me permiten agregar a la tabla de arriba productos encontrados por codigoBarras y otras validacionesla pregunta concretamente es la siguiente. si yo tengo este if con las dos listas llenas que me las compare y que en una tercer lista me muestre los codigosBarras que tengan diferencia ya sea positiva o negativa entre, factor y pedida y los codigosBarras que esten en la primerlista  pickingPedidosList pero que no se agregraron a la segunda pedidoEncontradoList gracias de antemano.

```
   if (!pickingPedidosList.isEmpty() && !pedidoEncontradoList.isEmpty()) {
```

Comment: Puedes explicar mas tu duda que no la entiendo

Comment: Tengo una lista que es pickingPedidosList esta lista tiene un campo codigoBarra y pedida,entonces cuando yo ingreso un codigo de barra que este contenido en  pickingPedidosList  lo agrego a pedidoEncontradoList yo lo que quiero es que cuando de click sobre un boton que yo pongo me arroje una tercera lista con los codigoBarras que no se ingresaron en pedidoEncontradoList pero que estan en pickingPedidosList  y la diferencia entre la variable factor y pedida. @RaulCacacho

Comment: Si quieres saber qué objetos de una lista no aparecen en otra lista, te recomendaría el uso de la función `.retainAll()`. Esa función se usa de la siguiente forma: `lista1.retainAll(lista2)` y lo que hace es retener en la lista 1 todos los elementos que también estén en la lista 2, y los que no coincidan son eliminados. Con eso puedes solucionar lo de "los codigosBarras que esten en la primerlista pickingPedidosList pero que no se agregraron a la segunda pedidoEncontradoList", guardando el resultado del `retainAll()` en una tercera lista.